# What is the difference between "naskiĝtago" and "datreveno"?

Tags: word-choice

Both are used for the English word *birthday*. Which one should I use for the specific date of birth, and which one should I use for the event happening every year/month/..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*datreveno* is more general. You sometimes also hear *jubileo* so it's not necessarily a birthday. Some people argue, that *naskiĝtago* is wrong because it's actually not the birthday in the sense that someone is born this very day, but it's only the same day of the year.

Personally I use *naskiĝtago* in the general sense of birthday and *datreveno* if it's not about a birthday but some other kind of aniversary, for example two years of marriage or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

According to PIV:

datreveno. Reveno de difinita dato

naskiĝtago, naskotago

So datreveno is "anniversary" and naskiĝtago is day of birth (birthday).